# Error setting up Raspberry Pi 4 + Electron + NextJS + external 7 inch touch monitor

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, touchscreen, electron

I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi 4 with an external 7 touch screen monitor using HDMI and USB.

I'm install **RaspiOS Lite 64 bit** together with my application and the following libraries:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xorg openbox libnss3 libasound2 libatk-adaptor libgtk-3-0
```

I've attached the monitor, installed and started my electron application based on NextJs. Got the following error message:

```
$ npm run electron

> testprj@0.1.0 electron
> electron .

[47105:1226/135035.294397:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[47105:1226/135035.294551:ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
```

I've setup $DISPLAY with the following:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
127.0.0.1:0.0
```

Here is my electron setup on NextJs:

```
/*
 * ELECTRON entry point file
 */
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 480,
  })
  mainWindow.setMenu(null)

  // Open the
  mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:3000`)
  

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Algumas APIs podem ser usadas somente depois que este evento ocorre.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

My config.txt:

```
$ cat config.txt
# For more options and information see
# http://rptl.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented
# /boot/firmware/overlays/README

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load initramfs files, if found
auto_initramfs=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Don't have the firmware create an initial video= setting in cmdline.txt.
# Use the kernel's default instead.
disable_fw_kms_setup=1

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]
```

My external monitor shows the Raspberry Pi console with login prompt.

How to make electron that setup works - show my application in the 7pol external monitor and use its touch interface?

Comment: `external 7 touch screen monitor` ... what other monitor is attached?